# Cancel a PositionStream in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I want to cancel a PositionStream in my application by pressing a Button. So my _currentPosition doesn't get updated anymore.

I already tried using the StreamSubscription (you can see it in my code below), but I just get this error:

dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called after dispose(): ToiletMap(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _ToiletMapState#4ccfe(lifecycle state: defunct))

This is my Code:

```
StreamSubscription _getPositionSubscription;

Future _getCurrentPositionStream() async {
    bool locationService = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if(locationService == true) {
      LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      print(permission);
      if(permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse || permission == LocationPermission.always) {
        _getPositionSubscription = Geolocator.getPositionStream(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high).listen((Position position) {
          setState(() {
            _currentPosition = position;
            _controller.animateCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
               CameraPosition(
                   target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), zoom: 18
               ),
              ),
            );
            locDistance = getDistance().toString().substring(0,4);
          });
        });
      } else {
        LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
          print('please go to settings and change location Permission from denied forever');
        } else {
          _getCurrentPositionStream();
        }
      }
    } else {
      print('locationService is unabled');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _getPositionSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

With the button I call the dispose function.

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  dispose();
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.clear, color: darkRed, size: 35),
                ),
              )
```

Does somebody know what I did wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `dispose()`. Just call `_getPositionSubscription?.cancel();` in the `GestureDetector`'s `onTap` method. Leave `_getPositionSubscription?.cancel();` in the `dispose()` method as well. This will ensure that the subscription is cancelled whenever the widget is disposed as well, even if the button is not pressed.